# Apply a function on a list of similar size tables, cell by cell

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe, apply

We are given a list of *n* `data.frame` or `matrix` of the same size (*r* by *c*), we need to apply a function over each cell of all tables and having result as a `data.frame` or `matrix` of the same size (*r* by *c* again).

```
For example:
a <- matrix(0:5, 2, 3)
b <- matrix(5:0, 2, 3)
c <- matrix(1, 2, 3)
l <- list(a, b, c)
foo(l, mean) # should retrun
2 2 2 
2 2 2
# For instance the top-left cell of 3 given matrices are 0, 5, and 1, and the mean is 2
# For all other cells, the mean of the values in 3 matrices will be 2
```

There are many ways to do the job, but I am looking for a very fast and short solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **abind** package:

```
library(abind)
apply(abind(l,along = 3),c(1,2),mean)
```

and of course a speedier version:

```
rowMeans(abind(l,along = 3),dims = 2)
```

Comment: +1 for rowMeans solution, it's reallllly faster for large arrays

Answer (score 2):

Here's an R base solution using `simplify2array` function

```
 apply(simplify2array(l),c(1,2),mean)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2
```

Note that `simplify2array(l)` does exact the same as `abind(l,along = 3)`

Comment: +1 for using a base function, however `simplify2array()` seems too much slower than `abind()` for very large arrays.